# how can i detect which key in keyboard is typed in java

Tags: java

Hi all here i am trying to detect the button clicked and based upon that i want to determine some actions 
Scenario is i must be able to do some action if a user clicks on up arrow or "A" button in the keyboard.. it is throwing an error as off now and is quite obvious

```
enter code here
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyChar("a"):


        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

How can i achieve it ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a KeyListner.

Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

So you create an `Action` for each `KeyStroke` you want to handle and then you bind the `KeyStroke` to the `Action`. The above tutorial will explain in more detail and there are plenty of example on the forum.

You can also check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) which compares KeyEvent and KeyBinds with working examples of both.

Comment: actually there is a mistake in the code i pasted case cannot contain || symbol i think it must be like this
      case A:
      case a:
       break;

Comment: @user3398900, the mistake in your code doesn't change my answer. The mistake is in trying to use a KeyListener. The better solution is to use key bindings. If your question is how to use the "switch" keyword properly then look in your text book or search the web for examples.

Comment: yea what u said is true i just wanted to correct myself cheers

Answer (score 1):

My mate and I did a project in which we needed this, and the code we used looks like :

```
public final synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    //stuff
}
```

This method is called automatically as soon as a key gets pressed.